# Combine two arrays into one array with object structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I would like to take two arrays with an equal number of elements in each, for instance:

```
colorArr = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
numArr = [1, 2, 3]
```

... and combine them into one array with object properties that are matched by index:

```
newArr = [
  {'Color' : 'red', 'Number' : 1}, 
  {'Color' : 'blue', 'Number' : 2}, 
  {'Color' : 'green', 'Number' : 3}
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, please add your attempt to the question

Comment: Can you share your approach you have tried for this?

Comment: A very simple list comprehension `newArr = [{"Color":c, "Number":numArr[i]} for i,c in enumerate(colorArr)]`

Comment: @RobRaymond that's what? Python? This is JavaScript.

Comment: Please share what you have tried at your end.

Comment: sorry yes python - filter was wrong:). concept is right,  list comprehension but in javascript `array.map`

Comment: @RobRaymond You might delete that comment then so it's not confusing. I believe the concept is reasonably well displayed by the two current answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
const colorArr = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
const numArr = [1, 2, 3];

let newArr = colorArr.map((color, index) => {
    return {"Color": color, "Number": numArr[index]};
});
```

edited: changed `colorArr[index]` to `color` as suggested in comment

Comment: Thank you and sorry for poor initial wording of the question - my first time posting. I had been trying map but didn't realize index could be used like this!

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` method. ([Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```js
colorArr = ["red", "blue", "green"];
numArr = [1, 2, 3];

// map over colorArr and get values from numArr
const output = colorArr.map((Color, i) => ({ Color, Number: numArr[i] }));
console.log(output);


// Alternatively, map over numArr and get values from colorArr
const output2 = numArr.map((Number, i) => ({ Color: colorArr[i], Number }));
console.log(output2)
```